# Почему не отображается кнопка загрузки у тега audio?

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

Не могу понять почему не отображается кнопка загрузки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код верстки элементарный

```
<audio controls preload="metadata" style=" width:300px;">
    <source src="file:///home/user/LOUNA%20-%2011%20-%20%D0%A2%D0%B5,%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5%20(clean%20version).mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Второй скриншот и код взяты от сюда
http://scriptgenerator.net/really-simple-embed-audio-player-script/

Браузеры Chrome 55, Firefox 49(только в них проверял)

Comment: Во-первых, отображение элемента никем не определено и может быть каким попало. Во-вторых, какой браузер? В-третьих, откуда вы взяли второй скриншот?

Comment: Отредактировал свой вопрос

Comment: Chrome 59, у меня кнопка есть

Comment: Вообщем причину нашел, вся проблема в том что аудио файл воспроизводится с локального диска. Интересно это можно как-то изменить? (это сейчас не нужно, просто спрашиваю ради интереса)

Comment: Я тоже пробовал именно file:/// с локального диска - и кнопка у меня всё равно есть, хз что у вас не так